Duplex printer custom size paper
I am looking for an inkjet printer that can print duplex with custom paper sizes. In particular, I regularly print on 8.5 x12. I used to have a large format epson workforce that did this. The epsom died and I got an HP 7740, which does duplex and custom, but not both at the same time. So I print on legal and then cut to size.
Since I don’t need large format anymore, a regular size printer the also allows legal, and custom size in duplex would be ideal. When reading the specs, I cannot tell.
Does anyone have a recommendation?
I hope this is not too off topic.

"I hope this is not too off topic." unfortunately, it is. It's a "shopping" question which isn't well suited for StackExchange sites (like this one.)
